# expected object-destructuring: '{ Network }' to have a typedef

Tags: typescript, ionic4, tslint, destructuring, capacitor

I have enabled this on `tslint` rule like so:

```
"rules": { "typedef": [true, "array-destructuring"] }
```

Here

```
const { Network } = Plugins;
```

It shows this warning:

> expected object-destructuring: '{ Network }' to have a typedef
>   (typedef)

How to modify this `const { Network } = Plugins;`?

[Capacitor Network](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/network)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add tslint rules make sure you understand them first.

First of all, the one causing that error is not `array-destructuring`, but `object-destructuring`.

And the error means you have to provide the type of `Plugins` object.

So should be

> const { Network }: PluginRegistry = Plugins;